# Quickest way to copy a 2d array in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have to code a program that inserts/deletes strings from a 2d array and is able to do Undo/Redo instructions as fast as possible. I was thinking of creating a 2d array for each insertion/deletion instruction, so the Undo basically copies back the old 2d array into the current one.

---

For example, my current 2d array is:
"1: Hello
2: World"

Then I ask to delete line #2,
so now my current 2d array is: "1: Hello"
and I want to create a new 2d array which contains:
"1: Hello
2: World"
so that if I ask to Undo, it copies back "1: Hello 2:World" into the current 2d array.

```
struct node{char** Instruction2dArray;
        struct node* next;}
struct node* pointer;

i=0;
pointer->Instruction2dArray=malloc(max*sizeof(char*))  //max contains the number of written lines
while(CurrentArray[i][0]!='\0'){
        pointer->Instruction2dArray[i]=malloc((strlen(CurrentArray[i])+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(pointer->Instruction2dArray[i],CurrentArray[i]);
        i++;
}
```

I wrote this simple code to copy the current array, but I'm pretty sure this is the slowest way to do it and I don't know how to do it quicker.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: if the data is all POD (no pointers to other stuff) you can just memcpy the whole thing

Comment: "but I'm pretty sure this is the slowest way to do it" Did you benchmark it? Is it really to slow and did you test which part was too slow?

Comment: @GradyPlayer But then he has to alloc more memory, for the maximum possible string length, not just the acutally used length and copy more data. If there is a huge difference in maximum vs actual length it could be a lot slower to copy everything.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I have to pass a test made by my professor, and this code is too slow to pass it

Comment: Why do you want to copy the whole array? Could you not just copy the part that changed?(I am not sure if i understand the problem correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Since, You have said you want more Insertion/Deletion Operations, Linked Lists are more preferable. If and Only  You need more Random Access, prefer 2D string arrays.

Linked Lists are more optimized for Insertion/Deletion Operations, In My Opinion.